# Accessing an Arraylist from Mainclass in other classes

Tags: java

Am developing a timer application and on process am stuck with a step. I have stored some values in an ArrayList and it resides in my main function . I have a separate timer class which triggers the timer for the event. Now I have to integrate the Arraylist with the timer class and make the arraylist accessed by the timers. But stuck with accessing the arraylist in timer class.

```
example:

// Timer class
class Timer{
public Timer(){

        timer=new Timer();

        t.schedule(new fn(),200);

    }

class fn extends TimerTask{

        public void run(){
           // arraylist has to be accessed over here

          } 
        }

Main class

public static void main(String []args){
//Arraylist with values stored 
}
```

Comment: there is no ArrayList in your snippet ...

Comment: maybe you can pass an arraylist reference in the timer constructor and access it creating a timer class field

Comment: @Sarthak Mittal- any example?

Comment: @Pratheep: I think you should try it on your own first and post what you tried if it didn't work out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the arraylist in outside of the `main()` method and make it static you can access it through Main.nameOfArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any arrayList in your example.

Next time you should put some more effort in your question and describe the problem better.

But I think I got what you want to do.
The easiest way would be to handover the ArrayList within the constructor of the Timer.

```
public static void main(String []args){
 new Timer(arrayList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, next time will improvise.